# SQL query based on datediff

Tags: mysql

I am looking to construct a query using the ad exposure and conversion logs, I want to identify the ad exposure that gets "last touch" credit for the trial start. The conversion should have happened within 7 days after the ad exposure.
Where Last credit means it was the last impression or click prior to conversion

This are my tables

ad_exposure_and_conversion

| user_id | ad_id | Exposure Time | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12368 | 574012 | 9/5/20 12:37 AM | Click |
| 12368 | 574012 | 9/12/20 6:02 PM | Impression |
| 12368 | 574012 | 9/13/20 5:53 AM | Impression |
| 13953 | 449785 | 9/14/20 10:30 PM | Impression |
| 17000 | 96336 | 9/1/20 11:29 AM | Impression |
| 17000 | 96336 | 9/7/20 8:10 AM | Impression |
| 17000 | 96336 | 9/10/20 9:43 PM | Impression |
| 17000 | 96336 | 9/12/20 1:36 AM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/2/20 5:41 AM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/4/20 3:31 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/4/20 6:05 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/5/20 6:22 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/7/20 3:48 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/8/20 12:04 AM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/11/20 6:00 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/12/20 6:43 PM | Impression |
| 22362 | 449785 | 9/14/20 6:05 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/1/20 8:13 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/2/20 6:14 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/3/20 3:23 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/3/20 10:06 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/3/20 11:53 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/4/20 8:07 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/6/20 5:06 PM | Click |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/8/20 9:17 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/8/20 10:32 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/8/20 12:51 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/9/20 1:30 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/10/20 9:49 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/12/20 6:27 PM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/13/20 6:22 AM | Impression |
| 23437 | 96336 | 9/14/20 3:39 AM | Impression |

I dont quite understand the last credit part as I dont have ad experience. But this is what I have done so far

```
select ad_id
from ad_exposure_and_conversion
where DATEDIFF(DAY,a.Exposure Time,GETDATE() )>7
```

Can someone share your thoughts

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: I want to identify the ad exposure that gets "last touch" credit for the trial start. The conversion should have happened within 7 days after the ad exposure. Where Last credit means it was the last impression or click prior to conversion

Comment: @yash Expected result = example table of data you would like returned based on the example data you have provided. Please provide a concrete example of the columns/rows you would like your `SELECT` query to return so we can guide you to that solution.

Comment: @Yash - That doesn't answer the question, just repeats what was already said in the OP.  Using the sample data, please post your expected results (also in table format).  Also, in terms of the data what is a "conversion"?